# Keyframe animation making image blurry

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

I have elements with a background image. I am using a keyframe animation to grow those elements on page load. The elements are becoming blurry and then adjusting about 5 seconds after they grow. Does anyone know a fix for this? Below is my code and what I have tried:

https://jsfiddle.net/ozy4dpk0/

animation:

```
@keyframes animation {
  0% { transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  4.2% { transform: matrix3d(2.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.549, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  8.31% { transform: matrix3d(2.768, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.884, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  12.51% { transform: matrix3d(3.064, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.032, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  16.62% { transform: matrix3d(3.127, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.063, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  27.73% { transform: matrix3d(3.026, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.013, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  38.84% { transform: matrix3d(2.995, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.997, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  61.06% { transform: matrix3d(3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  83.28% { transform: matrix3d(3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  100% { transform: matrix3d(3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
}
```

css:

```
#two-box {
  background-image: url("your-brand-here.jpg");
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #7f8c8d;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="two-box" class="first-row-styles animation-target"></div>
```

Comment: can you create a codepen or jsfiddle for your issue.

Comment: I just posted a JSfiddle @Rahul

Comment: Try using a larger image? In your fiddle it looks like the image is just too small so when the animation makes it bigger, it gets blurry.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0);
```